# Anaconda env says python is not installed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed python version 3.7.7 into a conda environment. I was able to run an application once, but after that python couldn't be found. conda list yields

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
.
.
.
python                    3.7.7           h60c2a47_0_cpython
.
.
```

Yet any python command doesn't work since python isn't found.
The terminal I'm using is git-bash, but it also doesn't work in powershell or cmd. A closer look in the env directory, I couldn't find a python.exe. The weird thing is, I was able to run and find python using that env yesterday.

Update: Currently I just created a new env with the same specs and packages, and it works - however that was the same position I was in yesterday. I have no clue if this is going to be a recurring problem.

Comment: use `conda env list` to see all the python environment install via conda

Comment: Yes the python env lists the problematic env

Comment: Another update, it seems python.exe is being deleted for some reason.

Comment: How did you create the environment? You're using Anaconda?

Comment: I'm using anaconda. In git-bash I used the command ```conda create -n blahblah python=3.7```

Comment: so si `blahblah` in conda env list ?

Comment: Yes blahblah is in the list. I should note that I was able to use python yesterday, worked on some stuff with no problem. Today I was able to run python once, my web app suddenly stopped, and python wasn't usable anymore.

Comment: You could try installing the Miniconda Python distrbution from [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and then use `bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh` to attempt a fresh install.

Comment: Python.exe is actually being deleted or Anaconda simply isn't seeing it?  Anaconda can be a bit finnicky depending on how you install it alongside pythong.

Comment: python.exe is being deleted. Displaying the path shows that the env's dir is being prepended correctly. Looking in the dir, python.exe is gone, but all the python.dll files, pythonw etc are all there. I had many issues installing anaconda's python alongside my previous python setup, I eventually just uninstalled python and copied my previous pip packages to anaconda's base env. No other python except the python anaconda is in the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate Avast. Honestly it should've been the first thing I've checked, Avast was quarantining the python.exe - and didn't even notify me! If you have the same problem and are flabbergasted, check your quarantine chest.